# Java Program High CPU usage

Tags: java, performance, jdbc, cpu-usage, apache-commons-beanutils

I wrote a java program which queries oracle database and converts it to object using `beanutils`

During `Load Testing` 
I found high CPU usage.

Outline of the program is:

```
List<Map<String, List>> rows = queryList(query, new Object[]{params..});
while(rows.hasNext()){
   beanutils.setProperty(obj, field, row.get("some column name"));  
}
```

DB returns approximately `350` rows.

Executing the program makes my CPU to spike 100%.

Removing the beanutils and testing query - CPU usage was 30%.

Now if I remove the `beanutils.setProperty` and use `getters and setters` CPU is not spiking(50%)

In `jvisualvm sampler` I find:

```
oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive()
org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer()
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Poller.run()
```

taking most of `Self time CPU`

I used `jmeter` to load test ( 20 concurrent requests ).
BaseLine of the `jvisualvm` graph is 0%. So definitely because of this load test only cpu is spiking.

Is it `reflection` that is causing high CPU usage?

Does executing a query eg: `queryforlist` takes CPU utilization to increase.

Later if my computation increases then should I reduce the number of threads accessing this api as it will spike my cpu again.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I did have performance issues with reflection in older Java versions (1.5 / 1.6).  I cached the reflected method calls before loops and that increased performance considerably.

Comment: reflection is slow. but your stack trace don't relates to reflections.

Comment: that's the same concern I also had. sampler says `oracle.net` but removing reflection brings down the CPU. Am I missing something?

Comment: Be careful with performance tests as they are highly subject to bad luck and misinterpretation. Try again without reflection and be sure that it is the only thing you change - can you repeat the results? You should post more complete code examples of both tests you perform.

Comment: yes the results repeat and what part of code you want me to post? I am testing with `jmeter` and hitting the http port.

Comment: what you see with `Packet.receive` is that this method call takes long which is simply because data transfer takes time. The CPU load caused by waiting on IO to finish is in theory 0% though. Higher CPU load can therefore mean that there is less IO wait in between and might be a good thing (probably not in your case).

Comment: But how does removing the `beanutils.setproperty` bring down the CPU usage. If datatransfer is the problem then CPU should have spiked in either case?

Comment: can you break the setProperty() and rows.get() into separate lines, and measure performance of each call?

Comment: Try to run Jmeter from separate machine & then load test your application.

Comment: @JmeterPerfTest Jmeter is running in a separate machine only.
@CharlieS: yes I can do that. do you think `rows.get` is consuming a lot of cpu?